# React-Native-Audio-Toolkit failed to prepare

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to build my own Recorder/Player using React-native-audio-toolkit.

Following their documentation but I am not sure how to prepare the record properly.

(on iOS simulator)

Here's my code

```js
const fileName = 'test.mp4';
let recorder = new Recorder(fileName, {
  bitrate: 256000,
  channels: 2,
  sampleRate: 44100,
  quality: 'high',
}).prepare((err, fspath) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('recorder prepare failed: ', err);
  } else if (!err) {
    props.onFileURIChange(fspath);
    console.log('fspath: ', fspath);
    recorder.record();
  }
});
```

The error is

```
recorder prepare failed:  {
    "err": "preparefail", "message": "Failed to prepare recorder. Settings are probably wrong.",
    "stackTrace": [
        "0   myapp                            0x000000010a2f61cf +[Helpers errObjWithCode:withMessage:] + 159",
        "1   myapp                            0x000000010a2f4cb3 -[AudioRecorder prepare:withPath:withOptions:withCallback:] + 2707",
        "2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e43e8c __invoking___ + 140",
        "3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e41071 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 321",
        "4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e41344 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 68",
        "5   myapp                            0x000000010a06edc4 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 2660",
        "6   myapp                            0x000000010a072f91 _ZN8facebook5reactL11invokeInnerEP9RCTBridgeP13RCTModuleDatajRKN5folly7dynamicE + 801",
        "7   myapp                            0x000000010a072a66 _ZZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEiENK3$_0clEv + 134",
        "8   myapp                            0x000000010a0729cc ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke + 28",
        "9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff519e2951 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12",
        "10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff519e38cb _dispatch_client_callout + 8",
        "11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff519e960c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 707",
        "12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff519ea044 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 388",
        "13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff519f40c4 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 626",
        "14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff51c096fc _pthread_wqthread + 290",
        "15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff51c08827 start_wqthread + 15"
    ]
}
```

Note: I tried with default recorderOptions but the same error :(

Note: This happens only on simulators. On real devices, it works well. :)

Comment: hmm nobody is able to solve my issue?

Comment: Yea, I think recording is not supported on simulators. By the way, I am having a different weird issue in playing local files on iOS. It will stop in random places and prepare() will fail without return anything. Have you faced this issue before? Thanks!

Comment: No, it isn't. Suddenly it is working as before. Never met your issue before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated your info.plist?

If not, you probably want to add the following lines:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>The description why you need to use microphone.</string>
```

Or add Privacy - Microphone Usage Description

Comment: Actually it is not the reason, but thanks for answering.